# MVC query string - multiple parameter collection

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get an optional list of strings from a query string, e.g.,

```
http://host/test/arg?mylist=cat&mylist=dog
```

From all I can tell, it should be as simple as declaring a collection in my controller, e.g.,

```
public string GetTest(string uriArg, ICollection<string> mylist)
```

When I try this, `mylist` is coming in null.

If I switch the controller to

```
public string GetTest(string uriArg, string mylist)
```

then mylist comes in as `"(Collection)"`.

Articles such as http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx say it should be as easy as using ICollection here. Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to reproduce the problem you are describing. This should work.

1. Create a new ASP.NET MVC 3 application using the default Internet Template
2. Modify HomeController so that it looks like that:

   ```
   public class HomeController : Controller
   {
       public ActionResult Index(ICollection<string> myList)
       {
           return Content(string.Join(",", myList));
       }
   }
   ```
3. Run the application and navigate to `/home/index?mylist=cat&mylist=dog`
4. As expected `cat,dog` is shown on the screen.